# one transaction for multiple jdbctemplate call and visiblity between them

Tags: java, spring, transactions, jdbctemplate

I would like to be able to call in a transactional way (to be able to rollback first call if second call was not ok) a first call of jdbctemplate which do an insert via a dao method and a second call of jdbctemplate which do an update via a dao method

The problem is that in my second call, I need to reuse the result of thee first insert which seems not to be visible, when I call my second call in my second dao method.

```
public class MyService {

aDao;

@Transactional
public void doMutlipleCalls() {
  aDao.method1();
  aDao.method2();
}
```

```
public class MyDAO {

method1() {
   jdbcTemplate.execute("insert...")
}

method2() {
   jdbcTemplate.execute("update...")
}

}
```

Do you see what I shoud add?

Thank you.

Comment: So revise method1 such that it will return the result , and revise method2 such that you can pass these returned result to it.

Comment: Ok otherwise without modifying those requests, it's not possible because commit will occurs at the end of the transaction?

Comment: Or maybe I have to call all jdbcTemplate in the same dao method?